# In which languages is function abstraction not primitive

Tags: function, haskell, language-agnostic, programming-languages, functional-programming

In Haskell function type (`->`) is given, it's not an algebraic data type constructor and one cannot re-implement it to be identical to (`->`).

So I wonder, what languages will allow me to write my version of (`->`)? How does this property called?

**UPD** Reformulations of the question thanks to the discussion:

Which languages don't have `->` as a primitive type?

Why `->` is necessary primitive?

Comment: Have you thought about what this question means? What would it mean to define your own type of function? Do you mean that you want to define more restricted or more general mappings?

Comment: @Marcin It clearly says I want to be able to define a function type within a language. I don't know any language that would allow it. Please specify, what do you mean by "more restricted or more general mappings", for me it is just "mapping", though I'm not a computer scientist. Maybe your answer will lead to the answer I want.

Comment: @Yrogirg I think what is not entirely clear in your question is if you want to define/overload the -> operator or if you want to be able to define a function object through the -> operator.

Comment: Yes, I understand that you "want to be able to define a function type". However, that is not especially meaningful until we know how your function type differs from the standard function type.

Comment: In other words "which languages allow me to define primitive types?", exactly none, that's why they're primitive.

Comment: @Marcin It should not be different. Just the same.

Comment: @Yrogirg So, you want to know if there is a language in which function definition is something defined from more primitive language features?

Comment: @dan_waterworth In other words "which languages don't have `->` as a primitive type?" or "why `->` is necessary primitive?".

Comment: @Yrogirg, It's necessarily primitive in any functional language by definition. You could define a closure type in C, it only provides function pointers which are arguably more primitive.

Comment: I can imagine that one can define a language where the ` ` (function application) operator is overloadable, but not where one can define (`->`) in terms of other things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean meta-circular evaluators like in SICP? Being able to write your own DSL? If you create your own "function type", you'll have to take care of "applying" it, yourself.

Just as an example, you could create your own "function" in C for instance, with a look-up table holding function pointers, and use integers as functions. You'd have to provide your own "call" function for such "functions", of course:

```
void call( unsigned int function, int data) { 
  lookup_table[function](data);
}
```

You'd also probably want some means of creating more complex functions from primitive ones, for instance using arrays of ints to signify sequential execution of your "primitive functions" `1, 2, 3, ...` and end up inventing whole new language for yourself.

I think early assemblers had no ability to create callable "macros" and had to use GOTO.

You could use [trampolining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trampoline_%28computing%29) to simulate function calls. You could have only *global* variables store, with *shallow binding* perhaps. In such language "functions" would be definable, though not primitive type.

So having functions in a language is not necessary, though it is *convenient*.

In Common Lisp `defun` is nothing but a macro associating a name and a callable object (though `lambda` is still a built-in). In AutoLisp originally there was no special function type at all, and functions were represented directly by quoted lists of *s*-expressions, with first element an *arguments* list. You can construct your function through use of `cons` and `list` functions, from symbols, directly, in AutoLisp:

```
(setq a (list (cons 'x NIL) '(+ 1 x)))
(a 5)
==> 6
```

Some languages (like Python) support more than one primitive function type, each with its calling protocol - namely, generators support multiple re-entry and returns (even if syntactically through the use of same `def` keyword). You can easily imagine a language which would let you define your own calling protocol, thus creating new function types.

*Edit:* as an example consider dealing with multiple arguments in a function call, the choice between automatic currying or automatical optional args etc. In Common LISP say, you could easily create yourself two different `call` macros to directly represent the two calling protocols. Consider functions returning multiple values not through a kludge of aggregates (tuples, in Haskell), but directly into designated recepient vars/slots. All are different types of functions.

Answer (score 12):

I can't think of any languages that have arrows as a user defined type.  The reason is that arrows -- types for functions -- are *baked in* to the type system, all the way down to the simply typed lambda calculus.  That the arrow type must fundamental to the language comes directly from the fact that the way you form functions in the lambda calculus is via lambda abstraction (which, at the type level, introduces arrows).

Although Marcin aptly notes that you can program in a point free style, this doesn't change the essence of what you're doing.  Having a language without arrow types as primitives goes against the most fundamental building blocks of Haskell.  (The language you reference in the question.)

Having the arrow as a primitive type also shares some important ties to constructive logic: you can read the function arrow type as implication from intuition logic, and programs having that type as "proofs."  (Namely, if you have something of type A -> B, you have a proof that takes some premise of type A, and produces a proof for B.)

The fact that you're perturbed by the use of having arrows baked into the language might imply that you're not fundamentally grasping why they're so tied to the design of the language, perhaps it's time to read a few chapters from Ben Pierce's "Types and Programming Languages" [link.](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/)

Edit: You can always look at languages which don't have a strong notion of functions and have their semantics defined with respect to some other way -- such as forth or PostScript -- but in these languages you don't define inductive data types in the same way as in functional languages like Haskell, ML, or Coq.  To put it another way, in any language in which you define constructors for datatypes, arrows arise naturally from the constructors for these types.  But in languages where you don't define inductive datatypes in the typical way, you don't get arrow types as naturally because the language just doesn't work that way.

Another edit: I will stick in one more comment, since I thought of it last night.  Function types (and function abstraction) forms the basis of pretty much all programming languages -- at least at some level, even if it's "under the hood."  However, there are languages designed to define the semantics of *other* languages.  While this doesn't strictly match what you're talking about, [PLT Redex](http://redex.racket-lang.org/) is one such system, and is used for specifying and debugging the semantics of programming languages.  It's not super useful from a practitioners perspective (unless your goal is to design new languages, in which case it *is* fairly useful), but maybe that fits what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Function definition is usually primitive because (a) functions are how programmes get things done; and (b) this sort of lambda-abstraction is necessary to be able to programme in a pointful style (i.e. with explicit arguments).

Probably the closest you will come to a language that meets your criteria is one based on a purely pointfree model which allows you to create your own lambda operator. You might like to explore pointfree languages in general, and ones based on SKI calculus in particular: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus

In such a case, you still have primitive function *types*, and you always will, because it is a fundamental element of the type system. If you want to get away from that at all, probably the best you could do would be some kind of type system based on a category-theoretic generalisation of functions, such that functions would be a special case of another type. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory.

Comment: Wow, a case where Unlambda isn't a joke answer!

Comment: This is definitely worth noting.  In some sense, a language _without_ function types seems strange, but a function with something _more_ than function types is fine.  The case in point example of this would be languages with dependent types, where -- for example in Coq -- you can read the arrow as a special case of forall.

Comment: >category-theoretic generalisation of functions --- btw what are they?

Comment: what about term-rewriting languages? Is there a difference between term-rewriting and function application?

Comment: @Yrogirg Please read the linked wikipedia article. As for term re-writing languages, they do not involve function application at all. You could implement a new language in them, but I don't think that counts.

Answer (score 3):

> Which languages don't have -> as a primitive type?

Well, if you mean a type that can be named, then there are many languages that don't have them. All languages where functions are not first class citiziens don't have -> as a type you could mention somewhere.

But, as @Kristopher eloquently and excellently explained, functions are (or can, at least, perceived as) the very basic building blocks of all computation. Hence even in Java, say, there are functions, but they are carefully hidden from you.

And, as someone mentioned assembler - one could maintain that the machine language (of most contemporary computers) is an approximation of the model of the register machine. But how it is done? With millions and billions of logical circuits, each of them being a *materialization* of quite primitive pure functions like NOT or NAND, arranged in a certain physical order (which is, obviously, the way hardware engeniers implement function composition).
Hence, while you may not see functions in machine code, they're still the basis.

Comment: you're talking about mathematical abstraction that is function. More then being part of CPU design, it is part of logic itself. The Q was not abot that, it was specifically about having primitive function type in a programing language. And you can have languages with none, one, two or more types of functions. You can have radically different architecture, like asynchronous dataflow. While on atomic level each component could use functions, that would not be the main abstraction in such a language. In PI calculus I imagine one has to work hard to have functions at all (not that I know anyAbotIt

Comment: @Will - If there is something like *the primitive function type* you can't obviously have two or more (different) of them. OTOH, you can roll your own, non-primitive, function types in most languages.

Comment: what about functions and generators, in Python? Aren't they two different primitive types of function? Or coroutines in languages that have them? Fortran's functions and subroutines?

Comment: @Will - if this is like you suggest, then it makes no sense to speak of *the primitive function type*.

Comment: I don't read the Q as being CS-theoretic; but rather about some specific programming language were whatever you can call is a function (more or less). So in Fortran there are two primitives called `function` and `subroutine`, which are perfectly emulatable in e.g. C with just one primitive of C, viz. `C function` (more or less). But in Fortran there are two. There are two function call protocols in Common Lisp, the regular one and the other signified by use of `multiple-value-bind` form. Ultimately boiling down to having several ways in which call stack is set up, and used, by implementation.

Comment: (contd.) easily emulatable in e.g. Haskell by returning a list of values, of course (except for such details as the binding of vars).

Answer (score 3):

In [Martin-Löf type theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_type_theory), function types are defined via [indexed product types (so-called Π-types)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_type_theory#.CE.A0-types).

Basically, the type of functions from `A` to `B` can be interpreted as a (possibly infinite) record, where all the fields are of the same type `B`, and the field names are exactly all the elements of `A`. When you need to apply a function `f` to an argument `x`, you look up the field in `f` corresponding to `x`.

The wikipedia article [lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_type_theory#Implementations_of_Type_Theory) some programming languages that are based on Martin-Löf type theory. I am not familiar with them, but I assume that they are a possible answer to your question.

Comment: Right, I _think_ I noted this in my answer (but perhaps it wasn't clear?)

Comment: Nope, turns out it was just in a comment.., oh well.

Answer (score 3):

Philip Wadler's paper [Call-by-value is dual to call-by-name](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/topics/dual.html) presents a calculus in which variable abstraction and covariable abstraction are more primitive than function abstraction. Two definitions of function types in terms of those primitives are provided: one implements call-by-value, and the other call-by-name.

Inspired by Wadler's paper, I implemented a language (Ambidexer) which provides two function type constructors that are synonyms for types constructed from the primitives. One is for call-by-value and one for call-by-name.  Neither Wadler's dual calculus nor Ambidexter provides user-defined type constructors. However, these examples show that function types are not necessarily primitive, and that a language in which you can define your own (->) is conceivable.

Answer (score 2):

In Scala you can mixin one of the `Function` traits, e.g. a `Set[A]` can be used as `A => Boolean` because it implements the `Function1[A,Boolean]` trait. Another example is  `PartialFunction[A,B]`, which extends usual functions by providing a "range-check" method `isDefinedAt`.

However, in Scala methods and functions are different, and there is no way to change how methods work. Usually you don't notice the difference, as methods are automatically lifted to functions.

So you have a lot of control how you implement and extend functions in Scala, but I think you have a real "replacement" in mind. I'm not sure this makes even sense.

Or maybe you are looking for languages with some kind of generalization of functions? Then Haskell with Arrow syntax would qualify: http://www.haskell.org/arrows/syntax.html

Comment: But still there is no way to reimplement `=>` (i.e. one can use it wherever the original `=>` is used), right?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the dumb answer to your question is **assembly code**. This provides you with primitives even "lower" level than functions. You can create functions as macros that make use of register and jump primitives.

Most sane programming languages will give you a way to create functions as a baked-in language feature, because functions (or "subroutines") are the essence of good programming: code reuse.